# Select MAX CASE WHEN query

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I have tables, they are:
tb_penelaah

```
-----------------------------
id_penelaah | nama_penelaah |
-----------------------------
1           | penelaah 1    |
2           | penelaah 2    |
-----------------------------
```

tb_skill

```
----------------------------
id_sill | nama_skill       |
----------------------------
1       | skill 1          |
2       | skill 2          |
----------------------------
```

tb_skill_penelaah

```
-----------------------------------------
skill   | penelaah  | status  | priority|
-----------------------------------------
1       | 1         | A       |  1      |
2       | 1         | B       |  1      |
1       | 2         | A       |  1      |
2       | 2         | A       |  2      |
----------------------------------------
```

SO I want to echoing data in a page like this (in PHP Codeigniter):

Detail for Penelaah 1:

```
Nama Penelaah : Penelaah 1
Skill A 1 : skill 1
Skill A 2 : -
Skill B 1 : skill 2
SKill B 2 : -
```

and detail for Penelaah 2:

```
Nama Penelaah : Penelaah 2
Skill A 1 : skill 1
Skill A 2 : skill 2
Skill B 1 : -
SKill B 2 : -
```

I've tried query like this :

```
function det_skill_pen($id){
        $this->db
        ->query("SELECT a.nama_penelaah,a.id_penelaah,
            MAX(CASE WHEN b.p_status = 'A' AND b.p_urutan = 1 THEN c.nama_skill END) 'SKILL_A1',
            MAX(CASE WHEN b.p_status = 'A' AND b.p_urutan = 2 THEN c.nama_skill END) 'SKILL_A2',
            MAX(CASE WHEN b.p_status = 'B' AND b.p_urutan = 1 THEN c.nama_skill END) 'SKILL_B1',
            MAX(CASE WHEN b.p_status = 'B' AND b.p_urutan = 2 THEN c.nama_skill END) 'SKILL_B2'
            FROM tb_penelaah a
            LEFT JOIN tb_skill_p b ON b.p_penelaah = a.id_penelaah
            LEFT JOIN tb_skill c ON c.id_skill = b.p_skill
            GROUP BY a.id_penelaah
            ORDER BY id_penelaah");
        $query=$this->db->get();
        return $query;
    }
```

But error occurred like this

> A Database Error Occurred
>
> No tables used
>
> SELECT *

anyone can help? I'm not well in sql query

Comment: What if you execute the SQL in MySQL console / workbench / phpmyadmin ?

Comment: OK, I've tried, the query is work well in MySQL Console. there are nama_penelaah, id_penelaah, SKILL_A1, SKILL_A2, SKILL_B1, SKILL_B2

Comment: well, I think it's problem in my Codeigniter model, I have to use $query=$this->db->query("SELECT....."); and return it : return $query;

Thanks for your answer

Answer (score 1):

SOLVED !!!

I've edited my Codeigniter model from :

```
function det_skill_pen($id){
        $this->db
        ->query("SELECT a.nama_penelaah,a.id_penelaah,
            MAX(CASE WHEN b.p_status = 'A' AND b.p_urutan = 1 THEN c.nama_skill END) 'SKILL_A1',
            MAX(CASE WHEN b.p_status = 'A' AND b.p_urutan = 2 THEN c.nama_skill END) 'SKILL_A2',
            MAX(CASE WHEN b.p_status = 'B' AND b.p_urutan = 1 THEN c.nama_skill END) 'SKILL_B1',
            MAX(CASE WHEN b.p_status = 'B' AND b.p_urutan = 2 THEN c.nama_skill END) 'SKILL_B2'
            FROM tb_penelaah a
            LEFT JOIN tb_skill_p b ON b.p_penelaah = a.id_penelaah
            LEFT JOIN tb_skill c ON c.id_skill = b.p_skill
            GROUP BY a.id_penelaah
            ORDER BY id_penelaah");
        $query=$this->db->get();
        return $query;
    }
```

to this:

```
function det_skill_pen($id){
        $query=$this->db->query("SELECT *,
            MAX(CASE WHEN b.p_status = 'A' AND b.p_urutan = 1 THEN c.nama_skill END) 'SKILL_A1',
            MAX(CASE WHEN b.p_status = 'A' AND b.p_urutan = 2 THEN c.nama_skill END) 'SKILL_A2',
            MAX(CASE WHEN b.p_status = 'B' AND b.p_urutan = 1 THEN c.nama_skill END) 'SKILL_B1',
            MAX(CASE WHEN b.p_status = 'B' AND b.p_urutan = 2 THEN c.nama_skill END) 'SKILL_B2'
            FROM tb_penelaah a
            LEFT JOIN tb_skill_p b ON b.p_penelaah = a.id_penelaah
            LEFT JOIN tb_skill c ON c.id_skill = b.p_skill
            WHERE a.id_penelaah = $id
            GROUP BY a.id_penelaah
            ORDER BY id_penelaah");
        return $query;
    }
```

and now work fine, thanks @Raptor for your answer and suggestion